# How to use order by creation list of files selected with Tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter, metadata

I'm trying to learn Python and my second project is this: a small file orderer.

**For some reason it's not formatting part of my code, please excuse me for the problem...**

**Until now I managed to do these things:**

- Tkinter files selection window dialog;
- Name selection for the sequential files;
- Folder creation inside the Desktop, so it will find the username and create a path to his desktop;
- Sequentially rename the files to the selected name and relocate them to the previously created folder.

**What I am struggling with are these things:**

- Using the creation date in my ordering sequence;
- Making the program work on Windows, it's currently working only on MacOS.

```py
root = tkinter.Tk()

filez = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Select files to rename (must be all of the same type!)')


lst = list(filez)

suffix = pathlib.Path(lst[1]).suffix


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("400x240")

ROOT = tkinter.Tk()

ROOT.withdraw()

USER_INP = simpledialog.askstring(title="Test", prompt="Name your files:")

username = getpass.getuser()

name = USER_INP
num = 1


newpath = r'/Users/' + username + '/Desktop/OrderedFiles/'
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)




for line in lst:
    dst = newpath + name + str(num) + suffix
    rename(line, dst)
    num += 1
```

**Time of creation getter:**

```
for line in filez:
    time.ctime(os.path.getctime(line))
```

*Feel free to try it yourself if you are on MacOS, I even created an executable file, but I won't send it if not requested for security concerns one may have.*

Comment: @JacksonPro I did, for whatever reason it's not working...

Comment: I did format it in many different ways, not working, let me try by removing some code

Comment: @JacksonPro I did it line by line, should be readable for helping me out now :)

Comment: the bullets right above it are messing up the code block format

Comment: @JacksonPro thanks for the help on the formatting :)

Comment: I was able to use your code in Windows (good job!), but I'm not sure if I'm using the program correctly. the problem you are having is the second patch of code that you posted right? you are iterating over `filez`, which has the previous location of the files. But your code moves them, so this location is empty, naturally giving an error. you have to get the locations again from the new directory.

Comment: @Orozco wow! Amazing news and thanks for the compliment! How can I passively get the original location from the first request without having to ask another time to the user? Also, how did you manage to make it work on Windows?